# C# Multiuser Database Connection

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am tasked with creating a central Database for a small office to allow multiple computers to connect to a database using a C# program. I have already written the program and it currently connects with a database that is in the bin folder.

I am completely lost as to how to move on to creating a multi user environment. I searched all around SO and tried downloading Microsoft SQL Server, but I have no idea how I would set this up in the office and allow it to be accessed from multiple computers. Also, from the information I've gathered, Microsoft SQL Server needs to be running at all times to allow a connection -- this isn't a deal breaker, but is there any other methods that wouldn't need this? There isn't exactly a "main computer" in the office that is always running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run a centralized sql server database in your office you would at a minimum setup sql server on a "server". The server can be pretty simple unless you expect a heavy user load.
The server has to be on in order to allow connections.
Sql Server exists in a free version called Sql Server express, but it has limitations when it comes to scalability, so it's not meant for large systems. 
You can download it and install it on your server in the office and connect to it through a connection string in your application.

You can also consider open source platforms like mySQl, but it would still require a central server.

Alternatively you can consider a hosted solution where you have a company host the database for you in their data center.

Comment: I emailed my boss and he mentioned that his computer is on all of the time. So if I downloaded SQL Server Express on to my boss' computer, and set the connection string in the program to go to that location (all on the same network), everything will work no problem? Lastly, does SQL Server Express actually have to be running after being set up previously? Or is the computer being on with the server on it enough. I'm just asking because I won't always be at the office, and I'd want everything to run as smooth as possible.

Comment: The database engine will launch as a windows service, so the sql server management studio application doesn't have to run in order to connect from other computers.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer and for all of your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Hi I know this is an old question, but can you share some references on how to setup my sql server express?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have the server computer in your office that will host the DBMS and allow others to connect to your DB using the web interface, try to use Windows Azure. This will cost you some money. Here you need to estimate what is cheaper for you: purchase a server or pay for the azure.